# Master Slave Memcache replication

Tags: linux, caching, memcached, replication

Scenario :

Our architecture is based on memcached and with increasing number of user base we need to replicate cache to multiple servers.

We were easily able to replicate between two servers using repcached utility.

We want to load balanced memcached in such a manner that it will work on shards which we define in our code.

The question over here is how can we replicate to multiple servers.

We have changed peer port for replication but still we are not able to replicate keys.

Comment: Have you considered looking into Couchbase? Couchbase provides all of this functionality and has internal sharding. Couchbase is of course a database and will also persist all of your data as well as provide a caching layer, but if persistence is something that is okay for your project it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been reading, memcached-repcached is capable of 2 node replication setup only. 
Some other options out there:
[alternative to memcached that can persist to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316852/alternative-to-memcached-that-can-persist-to-disk)

Good luck!